Attempting to find character position by defining player/character/root breaks script but has no errors
I'm trying to make a can of soda that explodes your character after drinking it, but it gets stuck after the first animation of raising the can (without exploding) and doesn't give any errors. Does anyone know what's wrong with the code? (I reused the bloxy cola code)
edit: changed out h.Position for root.Position, still broken
edit 2: tried different way to define root but still broken (no errors)
local Tool = script.Parent;
enabled = true

function onActivated()
    if not enabled  then
        return
    end

    enabled = false
    Tool.GripForward = Vector3.new(0,-.759,-.651)
    Tool.GripPos = Vector3.new(1.5,-.5,.3)
    Tool.GripRight = Vector3.new(1,0,0)
    Tool.GripUp = Vector3.new(0,.651,-.759)


    Tool.Handle.DrinkSound:Play()

    wait(3)
    
    local h = Tool.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    
    if (h ~= nil) then
        if (h.MaxHealth > h.Health + 5) then
            h.Health = h.Health + 0
        else    
            h.Health = h.Health + 0
        end
    end
    
--I think the script breaks here

    local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
    local root = character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    
    Tool.GripForward = Vector3.new(-.976,0,-0.217)
    Tool.GripPos = Vector3.new(0.03,0,0)
    Tool.GripRight = Vector3.new(.217,0,-.976)
    Tool.GripUp = Vector3.new(0,1,0)
    
    local e = Instance.new("Explosion")
    e.BlastRadius = 16
    e.BlastPressure = 1000000
    e.Position = root.Position
    e.Parent = game.Workspace
    
    
    enabled = true

end

function onEquipped()
    Tool.Handle.OpenSound:play()
end

script.Parent.Activated:connect(onActivated)
script.Parent.Equipped:connect(onEquipped)


The main thing here is manual tracing of the code. Put in debug messages so you can see intermediate values, and flow control, in your console. Which bit causes the explosion? Does it run at all? If not, what earlier code does run, and do you have a conditional that is getting the wrong result?

I tried recreating the scenario you described but to no avail.
When placed in the tool, your code worked for me in both local and regular scripts.
Here's the code I ended up with:
-- Defined player at top-level (LocalScript only)
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local tool = script.Parent

-- Renamed "enabled" to cooldown for clarity
local cooldown = false

function onActivated()
    if cooldown then
        return
    end

    cooldown = true
    
    -- Change position to drink
    tool.GripForward = Vector3.new(0,-.759,-.651)
    tool.GripPos = Vector3.new(1.5,-.5,.3)
    tool.GripRight = Vector3.new(1,0,0)
    tool.GripUp = Vector3.new(0,.651,-.759)

    tool.Handle.DrinkSound:Play()

    -- Wait for sound to end
    tool.Handle.DrinkSound.Ended:Wait()
    
    -- (Removed the original add health code)
    
    -- Get player RootPart 
    local root = tool.Parent:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")

    local explosion = Instance.new("Explosion")
    explosion.BlastRadius = 16
    explosion.BlastPressure = 1000000
    explosion.Position = root.Position
    explosion.Parent = game.Workspace

    cooldown = false
end

Hopefully, these slight adjustments resolve your issue...
